# How to Perform in_array for Associative Arrays in PHP

Tags: php, associative-array

Is there any PHP function to perform `in_array()` for associative array? I know how to do with a `foreach` loop, but is there a PHP function or more elegant way to do this?

Comment: `in_array()` should also work with associative arrays, please show us an example of what you want to do

Comment: `in_array` and `array_search` should work with associative arrays...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both [`in_array()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) and [`array_search()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) work just fine for associative arrays.

See these examples:

```php
php > $array = ['one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3];

php > var_dump(in_array(2, $array));
bool(true)

php > var_dump(in_array(5, $array));
bool(false)

php > var_dump(array_search(2, $array));
string(3) "two"

php > var_dump(array_search(5, $array));
bool(false)
```

Comment: i wanted to check whether a specific key has a specific value. I used array_search now. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 2):

**in_array()** function is utilized to determine if specific value exists in an array.

It works fine for one dimensional numeric and associative arrays.

Please refer the following example code snippet which depicts the use of **in_array** function to check existence of value in an **associative array**.

```
$a=array();
$a['id']=1;
$a['name']='James';
$result=in_array('James',$a);
var_dump($result);
```